# How to run scripts that use function of the main script? (parallel, python)

Tags: python

I have a main.py script with some function. Now I want to run other scripts (e. g. test1.py, test2.py and test3.py) from this main.py.
Instead of running the main.py with each script manually, would it be possible to run them with only one main.py.
They also should work "together" and get the actual values of the main.py if they get changed from other scripts.

What I'm looking for here?

Comment: Your question isn’t very easy to understand. Why not edit a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of what you want to achieve (which doesn’t work, presumably) into your question. See https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am looking for something like multiprocessing/threading I think. I want to call from the main script some other which will work parallel instead of sequential, bcs e. g. test1.py have some time.sleep in it but other scripts should still run. I do not have an example for now, because I am trying atm to understand if it works/how it can work. I could run the main 3 times with each of them it will call another script test1, test2 and test3. But int this example all of them have their own main and I want to try to get them all into one main which execude the scripts parallel.

Comment: If it is still not understandable, I will write later an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for possibly a Flask server. Flask is just Python but for doing the sort of stuff you want to do.

Check this tutorial out http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

Flask is more for websites but you can defnintely use it to make concurrent connections between computers/users

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world